# How do I test if a word is in a text file and append it to the file if it isn't in C++?

Tags: c++, file, append, text-files

I'm writing a nutritionist program in C++ and I want it to test whether a food entered by the user is within one of the text files for each of the five food groups. If it is it increments the value of "servings of (food group)", but if it isn't then it ask which food group the food belongs to and appends it to the corresponding text file. How should I go about this? I did something similar to this in Python where I read the text file into an array. Would this work as well?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will!

Then load you array into the `stringstream`..

```
stringstream ss(std::string(/*array, length*/));
char food[256] = {0};
while(true)
{
    ss >> food;
    if (0 == strcmp(food, "burger"))
    {
        //food has been found!
    }
}
```

or you can do this via `ifstream` but remember RAM is faster than HDD